# Values seems changing straight after Initial Save in Dynamics CRM Opportunity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I'm doing a Service Call to retrieve the Account details (currency, discount associated with the account) on the Selection of the Account lookup on the Opportunity form (form type == 1 // Create) using **Web API** in **CRM 2016 On-Premise**. Everything is working fine but when the opportunity is saved initially it's straight away coming up with **unsaved changes** next to the Save button after the initial save which is forcing me to do another save(abnormal behaviour).I'm not so sure what value is changing straightaway after initial save.

The Service Call is Synchronous and is being triggered on the change of the Account Lookup, well before the initial save. Any Help Appreciated!.

```
function SetOpportunityCurrencyAndDiscount(){
    var accountId = (GetValue("vm_accountid"))[0].id;
    var result = RetrieveRecord("account", null, accountId.slice(1,-1));
    var accountDiscount = result["vm_accountdiscount"];
    var transactionCurrencyId = result["_transactioncurrencyid_value"];
    var currencyName =  result["_transactioncurrencyid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
    SetValue("vm_discount", accountDiscount);
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("transactioncurrencyid").setValue([{ id: transactionCurrencyId, name: currencyName, entityType: "transactioncurrency"}]); }

function RetrieveRecord(recordType, alternateKey, accountId){
    var result = null;
    var entityType = recordType;
    var query = null;
    if(alternateKey != null && agencyId == null)
        query = "/api/data/v8.0/accounts(emailaddress1='"+alternateKey+"')?$select=name,accountid,_transactioncurrencyid_value,vm_agencydiscount";
    else
        query = "/api/data/v8.0/accounts("+agencyId+")?$select=name,accountid,_transactioncurrencyid_value,vm_agencydiscount";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + query, false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            }
            else {
                alert(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you save your record and the form is dirty again, open dev tools and paste this into the console.  It will show you which fields are dirty.

```js
function showDirtyFields() { 
    var Xrm = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('iframe')).filter(function(d) {
        return d.style.visibility !== 'hidden';
    })[0].contentWindow.Xrm;
    var message='The following fields are dirty: \n';
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function(attribute,index){
        if(attribute.getIsDirty()==true){message+="\u2219 "+attribute.getName()+"\n";}
    });
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(message);
}
showDirtyFields();
```

Another way of accomplishing the same thing is to turn on auditing for the entity.  The audit log will show you which fields were submitted.

Comment: Hi Polshgiant, I've tried both ways unfortunately i'm unable to get the dirty field details. when i've pasted the above code in the console i've got : Undefined. When i've enabled the Auditing on all the levels and on all possible fields, i've got this message: The fields changed by this action are not enabled for Audit tracking. If I disable the Retrieve (service call) function the behaviour is normal.

Comment: How about Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml()?  Does that show you anything useful?  Another thing you could do would be to open Fiddler to inspect the 2nd save's traffic to see which fields are being submitted.

Comment: Thanks Polshgiant!. It was the Currency field that i was trying to Update which was updating again for some reason.

Comment: From CRM 2015 Update 1, The GUID's are case Sensitive and has to be Uppercase when setting the value of a lookup. Since i was submitting the lower case for the Currency GUID due to this the Price list was getting updated further on the Opportunity.